# Enviar formulario array, php, mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenas, estos días estuve haciendo un formulario para guardar unos links dentro de mi base de datos, pero la verdad nunca había utilizado los formularios con array & pues he buscado muchísimos, pero en ninguno lo logro.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$screenshot = $user->filtertext($_POST['panta']);

if (empty($_POST['panta'])) {

    $_SESSION['ERROR_RETURN'] = "Debes rellenar todos los Campos.";
    header("LOCATION: " . LINK . "/screenshot_publi.php");

} else {

    foreach ($screenshot as $screen) {

        $query_add = $db->query("INSERT INTO screenshot (user_id, screenshot, date_add, stats) VALUES ('{$myid}', '{$screen}', '{$time}', 'Solicitado')");

    }

    $_SESSION['GOOD_RETURN'] = "Se han publicado tu(s) pantallazo(s).";
    header("LOCATION: " . LINK . "/screenshot_publi.php");

}
```

Formulario:

```
<form action="<?php echo LINK; ?>/screenshot_publi.php?action=add" method="post">
    <table>
        <tbody id="content_screenshot">
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre de Usuario</td>
                <td><input style="margin-top: 0; width: calc(100% - 10px); padding-right: 5px" class="inputgray" name="username" value="<?php echo $myusername ?>" disabled ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="div_screenshot">
                <td>Pantallazo #1</td>
                <td><input style="margin-top: 0; width: calc(100% - 10px); padding-right: 5px" type="text" class="inputgray" name="panta[]" placeholder="Escribe el Link de tu pantallazo..." required></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input style="margin-bottom: 10px" class="submitblue" type="submit" name="submit" value="Guardar Pantallazos" accesskey="s"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo en tu código la variable que necesitas guardar se llama `panta[]` debemos tener en cuenta lo siguiente.

1. `$screenshot = $user->filtertext($_POST['panta'])` en esta linea estas procesando lo que llega mediante un post, ahora que hace eso solo Dios y tu lo saben.
2. Luego validas que el contenido del post no esta vacio a un cuando ya lo asignaste a una variable de nombre screenhost ¿ como sabes que no esta vacia?
3. `$query_add = $db->query("INSERT INTO screenshot (user_id, screenshot, date_add, stats) VALUES ('{$myid}', '{$screen}', '{$time}', 'Solicitado')");` en esta linea tienes 3 variables definidas y solo veo que pasa una aparentemente.

Valida esos puntos antes de cualquier cosa.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si es esto lo que necesitas, voy a ponerte otro ejemplo para que lo puedas ver desde otra prespectiva.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="planta[]" id="planta1" value="rosa">
<input type="checkbox" name="planta[]" id="planta2" value="margarita">
<input type="checkbox" name="planta[]" id="planta3" value="clavel">
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
```

Ahora tenemos un array que se llama planta[] con los valores dentro de ("rosa,margarita,crisantemos) Suponiendo que se hayan marcado todos los valores, de lo contrario solo estarán dentro del array los valores que se hayan marcado antes de enviar el formulario.

Ahora para añadirlo a la base de datos...

```
require_once "conexión.php"; / el objeto $cnn viene de aquí

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES (:valor1,:valor2,:valor3)";
$result = $cnn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array(':valor1'=>$v1, ':valor2'=>$v2,':valor3'=>$v3));
```

las variables v1,v2,v3 serían los valores que quieras asignarlos a la columna

Comment: No me queda claro, ¿dónde estás asignando `$_POST['planta']` a `$v1`, `$v2` y `$v3`?

Answer (score 1):

Ya vi cual es el problema, pero igual no quiero eliminarlo por que me es muy útil.

```
function filter($str) {
    global $db;
    $str = $db->escape_string(htmlspecialchars($str));
    $str = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($str));
    $texto = trim($str); // Eliminamos espacios en blanco o caracteres al principio y final del post
    $texto = htmlspecialchars($texto); // funciona casi igual que htmlentities
    $texto = str_replace("INSERT","IN-SER-T",$texto);  // Remplazamos palabras que podrian ser usadas para alterar la BD
    $texto = str_replace("DELETE","DE-LE-TE",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("TRUNCATE","TRUN-CA-TE",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("SELECT","SE-LEC-T",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("ALTER","AL-TER",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("UPDATE","UP-DA-TE",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("inert","IN-SER-T",$texto);  // Remplazamos palabras que podrian ser usadas para alterar la BD
    $texto = str_replace("delete","DE-LE-TE",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("truncate","TRUN-CA-TE",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("select","SE-LEC-T",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("alter","AL-TER",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("update","UP-DA-TE",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("script","",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("SCRIPT","",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace('"','&#34;',$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("'","&#39;",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("<","&#60;",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace(">","&#62;",$texto);
    $texto = str_replace("(","",$texto);
    $str = str_replace(")","",$texto);
    return $str;
}

if($newsstate == true) {
    function filternews($str) {
        $texto = str_replace("INSERT","IN-SER-T",$str);  // Remplazamos palabras que podrian ser usadas para alterar la BD
        $texto = str_replace("DELETE","DE-LE-TE",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("TRUNCATE","TRUN-CA-TE",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("SELECT","SE-LEC-T",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("ALTER","AL-TER",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("UPDATE","UP-DA-TE",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("inert","IN-SER-T",$texto);  // Remplazamos palabras que podrian ser usadas para alterar la BD
        $texto = str_replace("delete","DE-LE-TE",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("truncate","TRUN-CA-TE",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("select","SE-LEC-T",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("alter","AL-TER",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("update","UP-DA-TE",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("script","",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("SCRIPT","",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace('"','',$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("'","",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("location","",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&iacute;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&aacute;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&oacute;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&uacute;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&eacute;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&ntilde;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&Iacute;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&Aacute;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&Oacute;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&Uacute;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&Eacute;",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("�","&Ntilde;",$texto);
        return $str;
    }
}else{
    if(isset($_POST) || isset($_GET) || isset($_REQUEST) || isset($_COOKIE)){
            foreach($_POST as $key => $p)
            {
                $_POST[$key] = htmlentities(filter($p));
                $_POST[$key] = filter($p);
                $_POST[$key] = filter(html_entity_decode($p));
            }

            //Filtro las entradas v�a GET
            foreach($_GET as $key => $g)
            {
                $_GET[$key] = filter($g);
            }
        foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $s)
            {
                $_COOKIE[$key] = filter($s);
            }
            //Filtro las entradas v�a REQUEST
            foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $k)
            {
                $_REQUEST[$key] = filter($k);
            }
        }
        if(isset($_GET)){

            //Filtro las entradas v�a GET
            foreach($_GET as $key => $f)
            {
                $_GET[$key] = strip_tags(htmlentities(filter($f)));
            }
        }
}
```

Esta parte es la del problema:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $p)
            {
                $_POST[$key] = htmlentities(filter($p));
                $_POST[$key] = filter($p);
                $_POST[$key] = filter(html_entity_decode($p));
            }
```

Si la elimino se arregla el problema con los array, pero los demás caracteres no tendrían el filtro y podría causar problemas.

PD: Este código no es mio por razones lógicas, por eso no sé manejarlo bien, pero hago algunas cosas basándome en el.

Saludos.